# Python plot- Change X axis scale and Plot threshold

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, axis

I want to change `x axis` scale. For example, I am reading a data from txt file.
This data is like `a=[ 1,2,5,9,12,17]` and I want to convert to this number this scale[0,3]. I mean this data `a=[ 1,2,5,9,12,17]` has 6 number but I need to scale these number in [0,3] so that my axis should only be `c=[0,3]`.I have other data c=[1,2,3,4,5,6]. I plot this data in normal way `plot(a,b)` but I want to scale this like `plot(c,b)`. I don't know which function I will use for that.

Other question, I used `plt.axhline(y=0.005)`, I want to change with linestyle='-' because otherwise giving continues line. How can I put max and minimum threshold with '-' ?

```
 Second question answer:
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.axhline(y=0.5, color='b', linestyle='--',linewidth=1)
    plt.axhline(y=-0.5, color='b', linestyle='--',linewidth=1)
    plt.show()` I solved my second question like this.
```

Comment: Are you asking how to only show values between 0 and 3 on the plot (so ignoring 5, 9, 12 and 17)?  Or how to scale the values in the array to be between 0 and 3 (e.g. turning `[1, 2, 5, 9, 12, 17]` into `[0, 0.1875, 0.75, 1.5, 2.0625, 3]`)?

Comment: the second one,  how to scale the values in the array to be between 0 and 3 (e.g. turning [1, 2, 5, 9, 12, 17] into [0, 0.1875, 0.75, 1.5, 2.0625, 3]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If NumPy is available you can use the `interp` function to generate your scaled values ([docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.5/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html)):

```
import numpy as np
scaled_a = np.interp(a, (min(a), max(a)), c)
```

The `scaled_a` variable is a NumPy array that can be passed to matplotlib's `plot` function in place of the original `a` variable.

If NumPy is not available you'll have to do a bit of arithmetic to calculate the new values:

```
def scaler(x, old_min, old_max, new_min, new_max):
    old_diff = old_max - old_min
    new_diff = new_max - new_min
    return ((x - old_min) * (new_diff / old_diff)) + new_min

old_min = min(a)
old_max = max(a)
scaled_a = [scaler(x, old_min, old_max, c[0], c[1]) for x in a]
```

The variable `scaled_a` is now a python list, but it can still be passed to the `plot` function.

Comment: People are so nice :) Thanks a lot :)